# I need to know how to send ether from one address to another address for my Dapp

Tags: solidity, ether

> I have coded the below code it executes well but the ether cannot be
> send only the gas fees are sent?

pragma solidity >0.5.2 < 0.9.0;

```
contract sendEther{
    
    address payable rec= payable(0xD694fab8b63BeF0149aa47b8333dFeAe7f55E9C7);
    address public reciever;

    
    function send() public payable{
        
        rec.transfer(msg.value);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need a contract to send Ether. Your used client will have ready functionality for it.

Comment: please mention which IDE you are using for a run this contract?

Comment: I used the remix solidity compiler online

Comment: so we can't send ether from one address to another using contract?

Comment: I have written a smart contract which sends tokens automatically when ether is sent to it. Now i need to develop a Dapp for purchase of tokens that's why i am looking to send ether to that contract

Comment: Your code is fine I can send ether from one address to another address successfully by your mentioned code.

Comment: but when i try to send my metamask is not asking for a specific amount to send

Comment: I need to send a specific amount and still i can't send it and i need to pass that amount as a argument
For example : I need to get a value from the user and pass it to the function and the specific value have to be sent from his walle

Comment: Lauri Peltonen is correct, you do not need a contract for this, you will make your users to pay more gas by doing this.

Answer (score 5):

#### Okay big edit now you've clarified:

In order to send given amounts to given addresses successfully via a smart-contract, you can have a `Sender.sol` that looks like the following:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.0;

contract Sender {

    uint public amount = 1 ether;

    function send(address payable _addr) payable public {
        require(msg.value >= amount);
        _addr.transfer(msg.value);
    }
}
```

The function requires that you pass in the address of the destination of the funds, and has a `require` statement that forces the function caller to provide an amount of ether greater than or equal to `amount`.

In your contract, you can make a setter for this function to control it yourself. If your receiver is another ethereum address, nothing more is required, just call the `send` function, sending along ether and the receiver will receive it.

If your receiving address is a contract however, it'll need a `payable` fallback function like so:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.0;

contract Receiver {
    function() payable external {}
}
```

---

#### Testing it with Truffle!

Initialise a bare truffle project in a new repo via `npx truffle init`. Then create two files in the contracts folder called `sender.sol` & `receiver.sol` respectively. Paste the correct contract from above into each of those files.

Next, delete everything in the `truffle-config.js` file and replace it with this:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    develop: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*",
      websockets: true
    },
  },
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.5.0",
        settings: {
          optimizer: {
          enabled: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now add a file called `2_deploy_contracts.js` to the `migrations` folder and in it paste this:

```
const contracts = [
  `Sender.sol`,
  `Receiver.sol`
]

module.exports = deployer =>
  contracts.map(contract => deployer.deploy(artifacts.require(contract)))
```

Finally, create a file in the `test` directory called `tests.js`, and in that paste this:

```
const senderContract = artifacts.require('Sender.sol')
const receiverContract = artifacts.require('Receiver.sol')

contract(`Test`, accounts => {

  let amount
  const acc1 = accounts[0]
  const acc2 = accounts[1]

  it('Should get the amount required for sending', async () => {
    const { contract: { methods }}= await senderContract.deployed()
    amount = await methods.amount().call()
  })

  it(`Should send the amount to a the receiver contract`, async () => {
    const { contract: { methods }} = await senderContract.deployed()
    const { address } = await receiverContract.deployed()
    const recBalanceBefore = await web3.eth.getBalance(address)
    await methods.send(address).send({from: acc1, value: amount})
    const recBalanceAfter = await web3.eth.getBalance(address)
    assert.isTrue(parseInt(recBalanceAfter) - parseInt(recBalanceBefore) == amount)
  })

  it(`Should send the amount to another address`, async () => {
    const { contract: { methods }} = await senderContract.deployed()
    const acc2BalanceBefore = await web3.eth.getBalance(acc2)
    await methods.send(acc2).send({from: acc1, value: amount})
    const acc2BalanceAfter = await web3.eth.getBalance(acc2)
    assert.isTrue(parseInt(acc2BalanceAfter) - parseInt(acc2BalanceBefore) == amount)
  })

  it(`Should fail to send the amount if < required amount`, async () => {
    const { contract: { methods }} = await senderContract.deployed()
    const { address } = await receiverContract.deployed()
    try {
      await methods.send(address).send({from: acc1, value: amount - 1})
      assert.fail('Should have failed!')
    } catch (_) {}
  })
})
```

Now go back to a shell in the root directory where you ran `truffle init` from, and run `npx truffle test`. Watch the tests pass.

If you read the test headings (inside the `it` blocks), you can see that we have successfully tested:

- Sending ether via your contract to another ethereum account.
- Sending ether via your contract to another smart-contract.
- Having the `send` fail if the caller does not provide the specified amount of ether.

#### **Happy coding!**

Comment: I need to send a specific amount and still i can't send it and i need to pass that amount as a argument

Comment: For example : I need to get a value from the user and pass it to the function and the specific value have to be sent from his wallet

Comment: Have edited to show you how to create and tests a smart-contract that fits your use-case. Enjoy! Please don't forget to accept it as an answer if it solves your question!

Comment: I think there is a type here `_addr.transfer(msg.value);` , it should be (amount) ??

Comment: @Ender - nope, the amount is just used as a threshold over which the `msg.value` should be.